# Liferay: Conditional include depending on language

Tags: liferay

I'd like to be able to conditionally include a different header file based on the requested content language.

Something like the pseudocode below

```
#if (language is english)
  #parse ("header_english.vm")
#end
```

How would you do that in Liferay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use themeDisplay.getLocale() is you are using jsps

check http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/4148692

Answer (score 0):

Tf this is part of your theme you can simply use the pre-defined variable $locale

```
#if ($locale = "en_US") 
  #parse ("header_english.vm")
#end
```

You might probably just want to test for the first 2 characters (i.e. the language) rather than the whole locale.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually need is:

```
#if ($locale == "en_US") 
     #parse ("header_english.vm")
#end
```

(`==` instead of `=`)